# Message after submitting

Tags: php

I have some Troubles with coding a message after submitting.

Here is the Code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['selected_name'])){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM artikel WHERE anr=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['selected_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
        echo "<h2>Artikel gelöscht!</h2>";
        header ("refresh:3; url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php");
    }
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>Artikel:
        <?php
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT anr, name FROM artikel");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($anr, $name);
            echo "<select name='selected_name'><br />";
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<option value='.$anr.'>'.$anr.' | '.$name.'</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Datensatz löschen" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I realize that this way the message is always there and don't disappear. My wish is to Code it, in order to let appear only the message after submitting, and then return to the main page. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which message you want to show after submitting?

Comment: @Macro Check my Answer, Logic is wrong in your code

Comment: I've tried it. But with your Code the message appears, and the page is going to refresh every three seconds non stop.

Comment: @Mad The message is "Artikel gelöscht"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem this way:

I've wrote a Code outside the main page:

```
<?php
require_once ("db.inc.php");
if(isset($_POST['selected_name'])){




$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM artikel WHERE anr=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['selected_name']);
$stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();




if (eregi("[0-9 [a-d]", $_POST['selected_name'])){
echo '<meta http-  equiv="refresh content="3;url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php">';
 echo "<h2>test</h2>";
 }
 }
 ?>
```

This is the Code of the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<?php
require_once("db.inc.php");
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="loeschen.php"  method="POST">
<p>Artikel:
 <?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT anr, name FROM artikel");
$stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($anr, $name);
echo "<select name='selected_name'><br />";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<option value='.$anr.'>'.$anr.' | '.$name.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Datensatz löschen" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this can be a help also for others.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send headers after you've already sent them (by `echo`ing the message). Put the `header` line before `echo` and it should work.

Side note: If this code is something that you plan to maintain more than not at all, please learn how to separate model and controller from the view. Learning and using PSR-1 and PSR-2 won't hurt either.

Comment: Also in this case, if i put the Header line before echo i have the same issue. The message appears after submitting, but after this the message still appear at main page and those refresh non stop every three seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script>
alert("You have selected '.$language.'");
window.location = "'.$SITE_URL.'index.php?view=view_service."
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$phoneno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phoneno']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='".$email."' AND status='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $errormsg="email already exist";
    }
else{
$sql="INSERT INTO register (name,email,password,phoneno,status) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$phoneno','1')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
        exit;
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<form role="form" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email address" required>
    </div>
    <?php echo $errormsg;?></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="tel" id="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneno" pattern="\d{10}" placeholder="Please enter a ten digit phone number" required />
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    <input class="form-control" value="" type="hidden" name="status">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use javascript for redirection with delay of 2 second:

```
echo "<h2>Artikel gelöscht!</h2>";

echo '<script>setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "e3_artikel_loeschen.php""; 
}, 2000); </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Move</strike>

```
echo "<h2>Artikel gelöscht!</h2>";
header ("refresh:3; url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php");
```

Inside

```
if(isset($_POST['selected_name'])){}
```

and Reorder it to

```
header ("refresh:3; url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php");
echo "<h2>Artikel gelöscht!</h2>";
```

**UPDATE:** Try this

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['selected_name'])) {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM artikel WHERE anr=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['selected_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        header ("refresh:3; url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php");
        echo "<h2>Artikel gelöscht!</h2>";   
}
?>
```

[**PHPFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/xzn5-csjj)

Comment: So i don't Need to Code }else{?

Comment: I did it, but still the same Problem. The page refresh non stop every three seconds, and message don't disappear.

Comment: @Marco is this form code on the same page as the home page?

Comment: Yes it is on the same page

Comment: @Marco you should have said that earlier... I've updated the answer try that.

Comment: @Marco If it still keeps on refreshing then use `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php">';` instead of using `header ("refresh:3; url=e3_artikel_loeschen.php");` as i think it might be causing a loop of form submission.

Comment: Sadly it don't works. Still the same issue. I'm going crazy. The first time after startin the page everything is normal. After submitting, the message appears, and every three seconds the browser ask me to refresh.

Comment: Ok i try your last Suggestion and let you know

Comment: Still the same Problem.

Comment: @Marco hmm It works fine for me: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/xzn5-csjj. Maybe you have extra header redirect codes?

Comment: I have only the link for the Stylesheet and  a require Code for the mysqli Connection.

Comment: I've could resolve it. Look at my answer and tell me please if it is ok. In my case it works. Thank you for your suggestions.